# How to return value from an async call

Tags: node.js, callback, coffeescript

I have the following function in coffeescript:

```
newEdge: (fromVertexID, toVertexID) ->
    edgeID = this.NOID
    @client.methodCall('ubigraph.new_edge', [fromVertexID, toVertexID], (error, value) ->
        if(error)
            console.log('ubigraph.new_edge error: ' + error)
        edgeID = value
    )
    edgeID
```

where @client.methodCall refers to the xmlrpc library. 
My question is how to return value as edgeID. Do I use a callback for that?

If so, should the callback look something like this: ?

```
# callback is passed the following parameters:
# 1. error - an error, if one occurs
# 2. edgeID - the value of the returned edge id
newEdge: (fromVertexID, toVertexID, callback) ->
    @client.methodCall('ubigraph.new_edge', [fromVertexID, toVertexID], (error, value) ->
        if(error)
            console.log('ubigraph.new_edge error: ' + error)
        edgeID = value
        callback(error, value)
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, callbacks are the usual solution for asynchronous calls, sometimes you have callbacks calling callbacks calling callbacks, callbacks all the way down. I'd probably do it a little differently though:

```
newEdge: (fromVertexID, toVertexID, on_success = ->, on_error = ->) ->
    @client.methodCall('ubigraph.new_edge', [fromVertexID, toVertexID], (error, edge_id) ->
        if(error)
            console.log('ubigraph.new_edge error: ' + error)
            on_error(error)
        else
            on_success(edge_id)
    )
```

The main difference is that mine has separate success and error callbacks so that the caller can handle these conditions separately, separate callbacks for different conditions is a common approach so it should be familiar to most people. I also added default no-op callbacks so that the callbacks are optional but the main method body can pretend that they've always been supplied.

If you don't like using four arguments then you could use "named" arguments for the callbacks:

```
newEdge: (fromVertexID, toVertexID, callbacks = { }) ->
    @client.methodCall('ubigraph.new_edge', [fromVertexID, toVertexID], (error, edge_id) ->
        if(error)
            console.log('ubigraph.new_edge error: ' + error)
            callbacks.error?(error)
        else
            callbacks.success?(edge_id)
    )
```

Using an object/hash for the callbacks lets you use the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) instead of no-ops to make the callbacks optional.

---

[Aaron Dufour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593105/aaron-dufour) notes that a single callback is the usual pattern in Node.js so your original approach would be a better fit for node.js:

```
newEdge: (fromVertexID, toVertexID, callback = ->) ->
    @client.methodCall('ubigraph.new_edge', [fromVertexID, toVertexID], (error, edge_id) ->
        if(error)
            console.log('ubigraph.new_edge error: ' + error)
        callback(error, edge_id)
    )
```

Comment: Even with one callback, the user of the function can decide what to do in each case, but basically, your answer: callbacks are the way to do it. was the one I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @lowerkey: True enough but separate callbacks seems to be the usual approach; jQuery at least uses separate callbacks for success and error conditions so it will be familiar to most people. I've (tried) to clarify this.

Comment: Most node.js libraries use a single callback with the error as the first parameter, which allows them all to talk to one another fairly seamlessly.  I would suggest that way over the separate callbacks.

Comment: @AaronDufour: If a single callback is the usual approach in node.js then you're right, it would be best to use a single callback to maintain consistency.

Comment: I'd like to point out that **you can** also use [existential operators](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) on just functions using `fn? args` or `fn?()` when it has no arguments. CoffeeScript will compile this into something like `if (typeof fn === "function") fn(args)`.

Comment: @Alasdair: True but I like the the "optionalness" reminder that the default gives you, I tend to use `?` in chaining (where it is a lifesaver for code clarity) but that's just a style issue.